# Eigenvalues of operator in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory

The following example was given in a lecture of my functional analysis course. So I know the solution, but I don't know how to get there.

The operator $S_L$ is given by $S_L: \mathcal{l}^2 \rightarrow \mathcal{l}^2 \quad (x_1,x_2,x_3,...) \mapsto (x_2,x_3,x_4,...)$

The question is what the eigenvalues of the operator are. I know that the solution is all the values $|\lambda_n|<1$ by considering the sequence $(1, \lambda,\lambda^2,\lambda^3,...)$. However, is there a way to get to this sequence from   trying to determine the eigenvalues in the following way:

$$S_L x=\lambda x $$
$$(x_2,x_3,x_4,...)=(\lambda x_1,\lambda x_2, \lambda x_3,...)$$
So you get the system
$x_2=\lambda x_1 \wedge x_3=\lambda x_2 \wedge x_4=\lambda x_3 \wedge ....$

But how do I get to the sequence $(1, \lambda,\lambda^2,\lambda^3,...)$ from here if I wouldn't know in advance that this is the solution?

Thank you!

Comment: For $x_1=1$ you get $x_2= \lambda, x_3 = \lambda^2,...$

Comment: If $x\neq0$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$ you know that $x_{n+1}=\lambda x_n$ for all $n\geq1$. Hence, $x_{n+1}=\lambda^n x_1$ for all $n\geq1$. Since $x\in l^2$ you must have $|\lambda|<1$. Also, any sequence on the form $(x_1,\lambda x_1,\lambda^2 x_1,\dotsc)$ (where $|\lambda|<1$) is in in $l^2$, and it is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$.